# Aggregating using datatable or dplyr in R

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I want to aggregate a dataset which includes time date and other variables. Now I met a problem when I want to record the earliest value of one variable during that day.I tried

```
dt[, .(new_var1 := dt[time==(min(time)), .(var1)), by = .(month,day)]
```

But it will return me many repeative rows. For one day, there will be many rows.

Comment: Try `dt[order(time),  head(.SD, 1L), .(month, day)]`

Comment: In case you're wondering about the negative reception of this question, it probably has something to do with the nonsensical code you say you tried (which has brackets that do not match up). It's also preferred that you make a small reproducible example, as covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
dt[order(time), head(.SD, 1L), .(month, day)]
```

#### Update

If we need the `max` and `min` values,

```
dt[dt[order(time), .I[c(1, .N)], .(month, day)]$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to get the max values and ealiest value at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using `dplyr`)

```
dt %>%
  group_by(month, date) %>%
  filter(time == min(time))
```

Or

```
dt %>%
  group_by(month, date) %>%
  top_n(1, -time)
```

**EDIT:** To get the min value for each date:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(month, date) %>%
  top_n(1, -var1)
```

For both min and max

```
dt %>%
  group_by(month, date) %>%
  arrange(month, date) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1, n())
```

Comment: Thanks! But I also want to get the max or min values not only the earliest.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can adjust the `wt` input on `top_n` or use the filter option: `filter(var1 == min(var1))`